# Flutter web cannot change the ScrollConfiguration of TextFormField widget

Tags: flutter, web, textformfield, scrollcontroller

I am trying to always show scrollbar for my TextFormField.
I am wrapping it a Scrollbar, but I am unable to disable the default scrollbar of the TextFormField. So I end up seeing 2 scrollbars.

I am trying to disable the scrollbar of the TextFormField using the ScrollConfiguration as suggested here for the same issue on the ListView: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99724

This is my code below. Is there any to achieve changing scrollbehaviour of the TextFormField

```
 Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Scrollbar(
          controller: scrollController,
          thumbVisibility: true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
              child: TextFormField(
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                scrollController: scrollController,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a solution may be to create in Custom Scroll Behavior that returning the child directly to avoid drawing the overscroll indicator.

```
...
 child: ScrollConfiguration(
                    behavior: CustomScrollBehavior(),
                    child: TextFormField(
...
```

```
class CustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {

// Here, we're returning the child directly to avoid drawing the overscroll indicator.

  @override
  Widget buildScrollbar(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
   
    return child;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    
    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The CustomScrollBehavior does indeed work by overriding the buildScrollbar. It hides the default Scrollbar. I am not really interested in the overscrollindicator, so I guess wouldnt need to override it.